# Is it safe to use private key for decoding a server message on client side?

Tags: encryption

Usually, this story goes like "client encrypts using public key - server decrypts using the very-safely-stored private key'.

Well, I have the opposite issue.
In a mobile app, I am using a web service library, whose API requires 2 secret keys from my personal account of that service. Anyone having access to these 2 secret keys can basically use them to call the same service's APIs as if it was from my app. So, I definitely do not want to embed those keys in the app as a decompilation might easily spoil them.

So I thought I'd store those keys server-side, and send them encrypted with a public key to the app. Then, the app would decrypt them using the private key stored in the app itself.

I know it's still not secure, but at least, a simple man-in-the-middle attack or a binary decompilation analysis will not scream "Service API keys here, come and get them!". The intention here is just to make it harder for someone to get a hold of those keys.

Do you think this would be a good idea? Do you have any other alternatives?

Comment: How do you authenticate to get the keys from the server?

Comment: there would be no authentication actually, I'm not sure if or how I could implement one for this ... Users of the app authenticate through login credentials, but this should not be user dependent.

Comment: Without authentication from the app a binary decompilation analysis *will* scream "Service API keys here, come and get them!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secure way to handle you private keys is to keep them on the server and never release them to the client.

For each approved action create a server endpoint (e.g. an AWS Lambda). The server endpoint knows the private keys, but the app just knows where the endpoints are. This restricts the functionality to only what you approve, but the endpoints themselves can be discovered and could be used by other people without going via your app.

The endpoints can use some authentication such as JWT Bearer tokens (see https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/ ) to ensure they are only used by the application, but this requires server side knowledge of who is registered with the app.

Alternatively, if the private keys cannot be used for actions you do not want your application users taking, is it worth protecting them?

There are good reasons for aiming to make things hard but not secure, for example, the cost of creating all those endpoints I mentioned vs the risk of someone abusing the private keys. Unfortunately that means someone agreeing to a compromise and I can't advice you on the best compromise.

Comment: I think I will still store the keys on the server, just so I can disable and replace them if I find suspicious activity. Thank you for your answer :)